# Using reduce to shorten a for-loop

Tags: python

From an array `Ns`, I'd like to derive an array `multipliers` as follows:

```
Ns = [3, 3, 6, 3]

multipliers = [0]*len(Ns)
multipliers[0] = 1
for n in range(1,len(Ns)):
    multipliers[n] = multipliers[n-1] * Ns[n-1]
```

The resulting array `multipliers` is `[1, 3, 9, 54]`. My gut feeling is that it should be possible to make this code more succinct using `reduce` or another built-in function, but I don't yet see how. Any ideas?

Comment: In Python 3 there's [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate), but you're using Python 2, IIRC.

Comment: Is there some reason you don't want the final element of 162 in `multipliers`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simulate the behavior of `accumulate` (see @soon's answer) in Python 2 with `reduce`. You have to manage the list by yourself.

```
from functools import reduce
Ns = [3, 3, 6, 3]
multipliers = reduce(lambda l, x: l + [l[-1] * x], Ns[:-1], [1])
```

Comment: Cute. Of course, building a brand new list for each item processed in `Ns` is rather less efficient than appending to a fixed list. But I guess that doesn't matter much if `Ns` is short.

Comment: @PM2Ring Well, I could avoid creating new lists with `lambda l, x: l.append(l[-1] * x) or l`. But that's probably not a good coding style.

Comment: I went with the `append` version of [user38034](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2162377/user38034)'s solution because it is one line and works in Python 2.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) with a custom accumulation function (Python 3 only, if you want to use Python 2 you could install [`fn.py`](https://github.com/kachayev/fn.py) library (or similar) or backport the function using the implementation provided in the docs) :

```
In [10]: from itertools import accumulate

In [11]: import operator

In [12]: list(accumulate([3, 3, 6, 3], func=operator.mul))
Out[12]: [3, 9, 54, 162]
```

And then just fix the first and the last elements:

```
In [13]: l = list(accumulate([3, 3, 6, 3], func=operator.mul))

In [14]: [1] + l[:-1]
Out[14]: [1, 3, 9, 54]
```

Answer (score 2):

`reduce` give you just the final result of the reducing process, so if you want all the intermediate values you can use list comprehension as followed:

```
>>> [reduce(lambda x,y:x*y, Ns[:i], 1) for i in range(len(Ns))]
[1, 3, 9, 54]
```

but that isn't efficient since it reducing again and again for each sublist.

Answer (score 2):

As my comment and other answers mention, this is easy in Python 3, using  [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate). However, from your previous questions it appears that you're using Python 2.

In Python, it's almost always better to iterate directly over a list rather than using indices. Your code could be rewritten like this. (I've changed your list name to `ns` to comply with the [PEP 8 style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008)).

```
ns = [3, 3, 6, 3]
multipliers = []
last = 1
for u in ns:
    multipliers.append(last)
    last *= u
print multipliers
```

**output**

```
[1, 3, 9, 54]
```

Note that this code does an extra multiplication at the end, the result of which doesn't get appended to `multipliers`. Here's an alternative that's a little more compact. Instead of using the `last` variable it looks up the last element in `multipliers`, which is slightly less efficient, and while it doesn't do that extra multiplication it does need to create a new list when it slices `ns`.

```
ns = [3, 3, 6, 3]
multipliers = [1]
for u in ns[:-1]:
    multipliers.append(u * multipliers[-1])
print multipliers
```